# How to construct a regular functor from a categorical interpretation?

Tags: logic, category-theory, categorical-logic

I have read a [lecture note by Jaap van Oosten](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/catsmoeder.pdf) and I am stuck on the exercise 84 in the article.

> A functor between two regular categories is *regular* if it preserves finite limits and regular epimorphisms.
>
> For a regular category $\mathcal{E}$ and $T$ a theory, show that a regular functor $\mathcal{C}(T)\to \mathcal{E}$ gives an interpretation which makes all sequents in $T$ true.
>
> Conversely, show that any interpretation of $T$ in $\mathcal{E}$ arises the unique (up to natural isomorphism) regular functor $\mathcal{C}(T)\to\mathcal{E}$ with the property that it maps the standard interpretation of $T$ in $\mathcal{C}(T)$ to the given one in $\mathcal{E}$.

Proving converse in detail comes hard to me. The problem is how to define a functor on a set of arrows of $\mathcal{C}(T)$, since the standard interpretation merely interpret $\chi$ as an *object*, not a function. Thus I need to find an arrow corrsponding to $[\chi]$ in $\mathcal{E}$.

My attempt is as follows: for an interpretation $[\![\cdot]\!]_\mathcal{E}$ of $T$ in $\mathcal{E}$ and an arrow $[\chi(x,y)]:\varphi(x)\to\psi(y)$ in $\mathcal{C}(T)$, find the arrow $\phi : [\![\varphi]\!]_\mathcal{E} \to [\![\chi]\!]_\mathcal{E}$ (and I guess that it is an isomorphism.) Intuitively, $\phi$ sends an element of a domain to the pair $(x,f(x))$ of the graph. Now the consider the composition
$$[\![\varphi]\!]_\mathcal{E}\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}[\![\chi]\!]_\mathcal{E}\hookrightarrow [\![\varphi]\!]_\mathcal{E}\times [\![\psi]\!]_\mathcal{E} \twoheadrightarrow [\![\psi]\!]_\mathcal{E}.$$

(An injection at the middle exists, because the sequent $\chi(x,y)\vdash_{x,y} \varphi(x)\land \psi(y)$ is in $T$.)

The problem is that I don't know how to find $\phi$. I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: I see that you have created ([tag:categorical-logic]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/categorical-logic/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I see that your [suggested edit was rejected](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/733675). While in theory I agree with the reason described there, in this case the name of the tag seem unambiguous enough to me. I went ahead and edited it with the text from your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arrow of $\mathcal{C}(T)$, $[\chi(x,y)] : \varphi(x) \to \psi(y)$ is a(n equivalence class of) formula(s) $\chi(x,y)$ from a formula $\varphi(x)$ to a formula $\psi(y)$.  An interpretation of $T$ interprets *all* of these as subobjects, that is (equivalence classes of) monomorphisms (Definition 4.7).  Let's say $x$ has sort $X$ and $y$ has sort $Y$.  Then $[\![\varphi(x)]\!] : [\![\varphi(x)]\!] \hookrightarrow [\![X]\!]$, $[\![\psi(y)]\!] : [\![\psi(y)]\!] \hookrightarrow [\![Y]\!]$, and $[\![\chi(x,y)]\!] : [\![\chi(x,y)]\!] \hookrightarrow [\![X\times Y]\!]$.  Definition 4.8 explaining what it means for a labelled sequent to hold for an interpretation lets us use the sequents defining $\chi$ as a functional relation.

As you've pointed out, the first condition lets us factor the subobject $[\![\chi(x,y)]\!]$ giving $[\![\chi(x,y)]\!]\hookrightarrow [\![\varphi(x)\land\psi(y)]\!]\hookrightarrow [\![\varphi(x)]\!]\times[\![\psi(y)]\!]$.  The third condition gives a subobject $[\![\varphi(x)]\!]\hookrightarrow[\![\exists y.\chi(x,y)]\!]$.  Now you *could* use the image operation to interpret this existential, but using the second condition which ensures that there's at most one such $y$ we see that we really have $\exists! y$, that is, "there exists a unique $y$".  It turns out this sort of existential can sometimes be interpreted as just a pullback meaning that this definition of $\mathcal{C}(T)$ would work just as well for categories with only finite limits.  In particular, you can show that $\pi_1 \circ [\![\chi(x,y)]\!]$ is a monomorphism and is reasonably interpreted as $[\![\exists y.\chi(x,y)]\!]$ assuming we (internally) know that $y$ is unique.  Another way to put it is, under these assumptions, an image exists for this morphism even if images don't exist in general. At any rate, the factorization of $[\![\exists y.\chi(x,y)]\!]$ leads to $[\![\varphi(x)]\!]\hookrightarrow[\![\chi(x,y)]\!]\hookrightarrow[\![\varphi(x)]\!]\times[\![\psi(y)]\!]\to[\![\psi(y)]\!]$.

Comment: I don't understand how the uniqueness of $y$ provides a pullback interpretation of the existential. Would you mind to elaborate it?

Comment: A partial map $A\rightharpoonup B$ is a span $A\hookleftarrow D\to B$. Composition is via pullback. A total map would be one where the left arm of the span is a maximal subobject. If you prove that $\pi_1\circ[\![\chi]\!]$ is a monomorphism, which you can use the second condition to show, then you can represent $\chi$ as a partial map $X\rightharpoonup Y$. You can view this as representing the formula $\iota y.\chi(x,y)$ where $\iota$ is "at most one" quantifier, i.e. uniqueness without existence. The first condition can then be rendered as $id|_\psi\circ\chi\circ id|_\varphi=\chi$ ...

Comment: ... as partial maps where $id|_\varphi:X\rightharpoonup X$ is a partial identity map. $id|_\varphi$ factors as $X\rightharpoonup\varphi\to X$ from which we can get a partial map $\varphi\rightharpoonup\psi$.  The third condition states that the domain of $\varphi$ is a subobject of the domain of $\chi$. This immediately implies that the partial map $\varphi\rightharpoonup\psi$ is total given the first condition which implies the domain of $\chi$ is a subobject of $\varphi$.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to prove $\pi_1\circ [\![\chi]\!]$ is mono, but I can't. Can you give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: For my ease, call $[\![\chi]\!]$, $S$ and let $m:S\hookrightarrow X\times Y$ be the corresponding mono. The second condition states that the pullback of $\alpha\circ(m\times id):S\times Y\hookrightarrow X\times(Y\times Y)$ and $(id\times\sigma)\circ\alpha\circ(m\times id):S\times Y\hookrightarrow X\times(Y\times Y)$ factors through $id\times\Delta$, where $\alpha:(X\times Y)\times Y\cong X\times(Y\times Y)$ is the associator, $\sigma:Y\times Y\cong Y\times Y$ swapping, and $\Delta:Y\hookrightarrow Y\times Y$ the diagonal. ...

Comment: ...  Assuming $\pi_1\circ m\circ s=\pi_1\circ m\circ s'$ for $s,s':Z\to S$, then $\langle s,\pi_2\circ m\circ s',s',\pi_2\circ m\circ s\rangle:Z\to S\times Y\times S\times Y$ canonically factors through the pullback. The factorization via $\Delta$ then implies $\pi_2\circ m\circ s=\pi_2\circ m\circ s'$ which, combined with the assumption for $\pi_1\circ m$, is to say $m\circ s=m\circ s'$, and $m$ is a mono so $s=s'$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)